# datetime objects in SQlite3 and python

Tags: python, sqlite, datetime

Trying to store datetimes in my database project using python and sqlite3. Here's what I have so far...

```
import sqlite3

def connect():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("road_works.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS road_works(id INTEGER PRIMARY 
        KEY, location TEXT, client TEXT, start_date TEXT, end_date TEXT)""")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


def insert(location, client, start_date, end_date):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("road_works.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO road_works VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
               (location, client, start_date, end_date))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

insert("M25", "Lindor", "2019-03-16 20:00", "2019-07-16 06:00")
```

At the minute the database takes start_date and end_date as text. I want to change that to dates that I can then start doing calculations with like counting down the days/nights until the job is finished etc.
The user will also be inputing the dates and times so I cant use datetime.datetime.now()/today()
I have been reading into datetime but its more advanced than I'm used to if anyone could explain it better I would appreciate it.

I have been searching for the solution for a few days this is my first project it may be a little out of my league but I appreciate your attention.

Thanks :)

fixed! Thanks for the help!

```
def insert(location, client, start_date, end_date):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("road_works.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO road_works VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                (location, client, start_date, end_date))
    start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no native [datatype](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) for dates in sqlite. The manual that I link to advises (see 2.2) three possible ways to store a date:

- TEXT (ISO 8601 string)
- REAL (Julian day numbers)
- INTEGER (Unix Time)

My suggestion would be to use ISO 8601 format, since it is standardized and unambiguous. Additionally, as opposed to the alternatives it is human-readable without conversion. And `datetime` objects have standard conversion methods to and from a string for it.

See examples below:

```
In [1]: from datetime import datetime                                                                    

In [2]: now = datetime.now()                                                                             

In [3]: now                                                                                              
Out[3]: datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 3, 14, 53, 38, 596477)

In [4]: string = now.isoformat()                                                                         

In [5]: string                                                                                           
Out[5]: '2019-01-03T14:53:38.596477'

In [6]: datetime.fromisoformat(string)                                                                   
Out[6]: datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 3, 14, 53, 38, 596477)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I didnt know that I have been trying cur.execute('start_date DATETIME') :D.
I will give your solution a try soon and let you know how I get on. Thanks again really appreciate the help.

Comment: Hi I have put this in my code now. I got a 'ValueError: time data does not match format' when I tested if a normal string would work so it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [datetime.strtime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to convert a string to datetime object

e.g.

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime_object = datetime.strptime('2019-03-16 20:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/466376/3358570)

Comment: Thanks for the response I will do more reading on that topic. Much appreciated.